# Automatic Slowmode Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I've been trying to create a system that automatically sets the slowmode in a channel to a certain amount depending on how many messages have been sent. Lua is my primary language, and not Node.js, therefore I'm having quite a bit of trouble as to how I would go about this. If anyone had any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: SS4APPHIRE, please check out [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and clarify your question, to get good answers. Asking for "suggestions", won't get you  much help, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go about it:

Use discord.js's `<TextChannel>.setRateLimitPerUser(number)`
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setRateLimitPerUser

Not sure if this actually does what you want though, the other option is creating a session storage of the text channels msgCount and compare it to time, i found `setRateLimitPerUser` in the middle of writing the code so didn't finish it, be here's a start:

```js
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client();

client.slowdown = new Collection();

client.on("message", msg => {
    const id = msg.channel.id;
    const attempt = client.slowdown.get(id);
    //4 messages at most per second
    const ratio = 4;
    //look at last how many seconds
    const timeSpace = 5;

    //TODO: check if channel already has cooldown

    if (attempt) {
        attempt.msgCount++;
        const currentTime = Date.now();
        const timePassed = (currentTime - attempt.time) / 1000;

        if (attempt.msgCount >= ratio && attempt.msgCount / timePassed >= ratio) {
            //setCoolDown
        }

        if (timePassed >= timeSpace) {
            attempt.time = currentTime;
            attempt.msgCount = 0;
        }

    } else {
        client.slowdown.set(id, {
            time: Date.now(),
            msgCount: 1
        });
    }
});
```